# Getting sqlite OperationalError for function json_contains_path in SQLite while running unit test cases

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, flask, python-unittest

This is a function I have written which returns results based on the search key

```
def search():
    key = request.args.get("search")
    query = db.session.query(Company)
    query = query.filter((Company.name.like('%' + key + '%')) |
                         (Company.department.like('%' + key + '%')) |
                         (func.json_contains_path(func.lower(Company.app_config),'one',
                          *map(lambda app: f'$.applications.{app.lower()}', get_applications_from_key(key.lower())))))
```

Now whenever I test this api on postman it gives me proper results without any errors, even the web app works fine, but when I run my unit test scripts I get this error

`cursor.execute(statement, parameters)\nsqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: json_contains_path`

this is my unit test code

```
def test_business_roles_with_search_key(self):
        with patch("src.middleware.auth_token_middleware.requests.post") as MOCK_POST:
            MOCK_POST.return_value.status_code = 200

            TECH = "TECH"
            FINANCE = "FINANCE"
            ALL = "ALL"

            no_of_tech_roles = 2
            no_of_finance_roles = 3

            # GET roles by care department
            self.create_multiple_roles(no_of_roles=no_of_tech_roles, department=TECH)

            # GET roles by finance department
            self.create_multiple_roles(no_of_roles=no_of_finance_roles, department=FINANCE)

            all_roles, status_all_roles = self.roles_by_department(department=ALL)
            all_roles = all_roles['data']

            all_roles_list = [all_roles[current_index]['name'] for current_index in range(len(all_roles))]

            # Search for Finance
            search_results_for_dept, status_for_search_with_dept = self.search_roles_with_key(search_key=FINANCE)
            search_results_for_dept = search_results_for_dept['data']

            self.assertEqual(len(search_results_for_dept), no_of_finance_roles)
            self.assertEqual(status_for_search_with_dept, 200)
```

Also the `sqlite3` version is `3.32.3`
How is this possible that it runs perfectly fine when called using postman but fails for testcases.

Comment: I think you have mixed up MySQL and SQLite. These are different products, with different features and different functions. There is no such thing as "mysqlite3".

Comment: Thank You, @BillKarwin. I have now edited the question properly

Comment: `no such function: json_contains_path` in SQLite.

Comment: @forpas Made the change

Comment: What change? You can't use the function `json_contains_path()` because it does not exist in SQLite.

Comment: Read this: https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html

Comment: Okay @forpas, but then the same function runs fine without any errors while I test the same on Postman. json_contains_path is a Mysql function.

Comment: This means that you run the same code on 2 different platforms.